# Multiple horizontal lines on candlestick in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Looking for a way to implement something similar to the prototype on the picture.

I went through the Highcharts docs, but it seems that the only way to achieve this is to extend Highcharts with some custom code. Are there any other options?

A different library would work too, however Highcharts is already used in a bunch of other screens of the app.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Igor, You are right, with using Highcharts you will need to add some custom code, but implementing this feature won't be difficult. How the small, white horizontal lines should be related to data?

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek, thank you for looking at this! Horizontal lines mark frequently occuring points within the range. Here's an example:
Look at the first blue bar on the left, the range is 5000 - 6000. Frequent points are 5200, 5650 and 5800, they look like horizontal bars on the chart.

Comment: Thanks for the info! It looks that it is enough to use `columnrange` and `scatter` series types. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xome9u1k/

Comment: This does look promising! Thank you for the JSFiddle example, makes it easier to, well, fiddle around with the example :)

Comment: No problem. I will try to help in case of some issues :)